# Android View onDraw() Question

Tags: android

I'm wondering, will it be possible **not working with a thread**? could i still update the View's Canvas every time i will try to put an image every touch event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't have to create a thread, just put your drawing stuff in the overrided method
 View.onDraw

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
     // blah blah blah........
}
```

Call View.invalidate everytime when updating is needed.